# how to match string value in" if else" condition in android?

Tags: android, listview

here i am displaying 1 listview which is coming from server.if i click on any item  i want some alertbox to open...but for that i need match the condition eg.if listitem string matches with "Bianca pizza" then open alertbox else toast "hello"..here in my code its not taking listview item string .

its weird its taking 1st value of listview item in toast (the code which i put before if condition just to check whether its correct or not.)but when i am comparing its not working.

like in toast i m getting "Bianca pizza" but when i want to compare it with "Bianca Pizza" it should match and go inside the if condition but its not going inside and showing else condition.

here is my code:

```
    public class SubMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "id";
    static String COUNTRY = "name";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String status="";
    static String FLAG = "image";
    Integer i = 1;
    String _stringVal;





    private static String url_create_book = "http://cloud....com/broccoli/creatinfo.php";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_menu);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String SelectedId = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // Get the view from listview_main.xml

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        // @Override
        //  protected void onPreExecute() {
        //  super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        //   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        //   mProgressDialog.setTitle("Categories of Main categories.....");
        // Set progressdialog message
        //  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //  mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        //  mProgressDialog.show();
        // }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonarray = JsonFunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://cloud....com/broccoli/menu_typeitem.php?id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(SubMenu.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        }


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long rowId) {

            TextView name = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.type1);


            Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "this is "+name.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            if ( name.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Bian‌​‌​ca Pizza"))
            {
           //open alertbox
            }
             else{

                Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

here is my listview adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView id;
        TextView name;
        TextView population;
        CircleImageView image;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item1, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
       // id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idq);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type1);


        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        image = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subimg);
      //  icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
      //  id.setText(resultp.get(SubMenu.RANK));
        name.setText(resultp.get(SubMenu.COUNTRY));

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(SubMenu.FLAG), image);
      //  imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(SubMenu.FLAG), icon);
        // Capture ListView item click
        /**itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
        // Pass all data rank
        intent.putExtra("rank", resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
        // Pass all data country
        intent.putExtra("country", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
        // Pass all data population
        intent.putExtra("population",resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
        // Pass all data flag
        intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));
        // Start SingleItemView Class
        context.startActivity(intent);

        }
        });*/
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: do with switch in string https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: You mean, It should be case sensitive?

Comment: try equals instead of equalsIgnoreCase .....

Comment: try `name.getText().toString().trim().equ...`

Comment: i tried equals u can see in my code ..its not taking

Comment: "Bianca pizza"  and "Bianca Pizza", are they consider same ? I not sure

Comment: see the item are coming from database that is Bianca Pizza.etc..and i am comparing it with my string

Comment: Check my answer @z.al . You did a small mistake ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you used `parent` ! parent is the whole adapter view and it contains lots of rows in which there is a `Textview` with id `R.id.type1. When you use parent, it find the first item with that id in its hierarchy. That's why it always return first item.

you should do this :

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long rowId) {

        // TextView name = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.type1); WRONG
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type1);
        Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "this is "+name.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if ( name.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Bian‌​‌​ca Pizza"))
        {
       //open alertbox
        }
        else {
          Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: but if i toast the name its not giving me item string its giving me whole object string

Comment: it shud show the item wotever item i click in listview

Comment: now in toast the value is showing correctly ....but when i am comparing it "Bianca Pizza" which is showing me toast correctly...that is not coming true instead its going to else part

Comment: half way its showing the correct value in toast but still when comparing not going inside the if condition

Answer (score 1):

The only change you would need to do is Use view instead of parent on onItemClick, please refer below - This will get the clicked item text directly.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long rowId) {

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type1);


        Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "this is "+name.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        if ( name.getText().toString().equals("Bian‌​‌​ca Pizza"))
        {
       //open alertbox
        }
         else{
            Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: half way its showing the correct value in toast but still when comparing not going inside the if condition –

Comment: why its not comparing both are same then also its going to else condition

Comment: I suggest you can use equals method `name.getText().toString().equals("Bian‌​‌​ca Pizza")` - I have updated my answer please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this helpful for you.**

Firstly you close DownloadJSON class before on item click then call onitem click function.

```
 private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements    
 AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    // @Override
    //  protected void onPreExecute() {
    //  super.onPreExecute();
    // Create a progressdialog
    //   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
    // Set progressdialog title
    //   mProgressDialog.setTitle("Categories of Main categories.....");
    // Set progressdialog message
    //  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    //  mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    // Show progressdialog
    //  mProgressDialog.show();
    // }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonarray = JsonFunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://cloud....com/broccoli/menu_typeitem.php?id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));
                map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(SubMenu.this, arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }
}
```

In if condition write this.

```
if( name.getText().toString().equals("Bian‌​‌​ca Pizza")){

}else{

Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

                     or

if( name.getText().toString().matches("Bian‌​‌​ca Pizza")){

}else{

Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: no error ..when i tried it with Cheese Pizza its working but when with Bianca Pizza its not

Comment: please check bianca pizza write proper may be before or after i think its get extra space so its not match. when you get in name.getText().toString(). Because after string extra space not visible, you need to check.

Comment: count string length.